# How to correctly setup devServer for WebSocket proxying in a vue-cli app

Tags: node.js, websocket, connection, http-proxy

I have a Node.JS server running at *http://localhost:8080* with 2 routes:

- `"/"`: Serves */public/index.html*.
- `"/rest"`: Returns `{ ok: true }`.

This server is also running a Websocket connection *on the same port*. Inside *index.html* I connect to the server with `const socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host)`.

When I run this server and visit *http://localhost:8080* the following works:

- Index is served: Yes ✅
- The JSON is returned: Yes ✅
- WebSocket messaging: Yes ✅

---

Additionally, I am also running a *vue-cli* app at *http://localhost:8079* in development mode with the following *vue.config.js* configuration:

```js
...
devServer: {
  port: 8079,
  "/": {
    target: "http://localhost:8080/",
    ws: true
  },
}
```

When I run this app and visit *http://localhost:8079* the following happens:

- Index is served: Yes ✅, it means the proxy is working for this route.
- The JSON is returned: Yes ✅, it means the proxy is working for this route.
- WebSockets messaging: No ❌, I get the error *"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8079/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"*

---

#### What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it?

As you can see I have included `ws: true` which is used to proxy WebSocket connections as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have the following in the vue.config.js:

```
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8089',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
```

The websocket backend runs on port 8089.
All ws traffic proxied to the backend.