# vuejs cross origin blocked

Tags: vue.js, vuex, cross-origin-read-blocking

I opened the console on my browser, and I found an error message how to resolve cross on vue js?

[image]

I created a file called vue.config.js
and this , but not work

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/',
}
}
```

I run my web on localhost
'http://localhost:8080/'

How to deal with this?

Comment: The purpose of `proxy` is to specify remote server that is supposed to be proxied to local one. If you run Vue devserver at localhost:8080 , don't do requests to another address (...1.9 on the screenshot) but specify ...1.9:8080 in `proxy`.

Comment: oke i try again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has something to do with WebSockets.

Can you try this syntax?

```html
proxy: { '/': { target: 'http://localhost:8080', ws: true }, }
```

More info [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver).
Maybe check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63873336/16758153) question tho (WebSockets!).